# Subtract a Value from a Column and Store the results in a new Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Suppose I have a table:

```
names
```

I want to subtract 300 from its column:

```
salary
```

and store the results in a new column as:

```
newsalary
```

I know how can I have the results using:

```
select salary-300 as newsalary from names;
```

so it works but I need to store the results in a new Column and update my table I have been trying:

```
update names set newsalary=(salary-300);
```

I am just new to SQL SERVER 2008 and trying to learn it please help me is it me doing something wrong or...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Currently don't see anything wrong with your update query... Have you added the `newsalary` column to your table? Something like `ALTER TABLE names ADD newsalary INT`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a column "newsalary" for your update query to run. Otherwise that query is fine.